# Rendering a component directive in Vue 2 without params

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an app that holds the student list data. The component is supposed to take in that list and render a select dropdown (with select2).

In the fiddles console, it's displaying `jQuery is not defined`. I thought all fiddles now included jQuery?

I'm really not sure why this is breaking the all together. Is there something wrong with my directive? I know with Vue 2.0 they removed `params`, but this should suffice. Any eyes on my code would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Define component
var studentsComponent = Vue.extend({
  props: ['students'],
  data(): {
    return {}
  },
  methods:{},
  directives: {
    select: {
        bind: function () {
        var self = this;
        var select = $('#select-student');

        select.select2();
        select.on('change', function () {
            console.log('hey on select works!');
         });
            },
      update: function (oldVal, newVal) {
        var select = $('#select-student');
        select.val(newVal).trigger('change');
      }
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div>
        <select
        ref=""
        id="select-student"
        v-select>
            <option value="0">Select Student</option>
            <option
            v-for="(student, index) in students" 
            :value="student.id">
            {{ student.name }}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
  `,
});

// Register component
Vue.component('students-component', studentsComponent);

// App
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    students: [
        { name: 'Jack', id: 0 },
      { name: 'Kate', id: 1 },
      { name: 'Sawyer', id: 2 },
      { name: 'John', id: 3 },
      { name: 'Desmond', id: 4 },
    ]
  },
});
```

I made a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hts8nrjd/4/ for reference. Thank you for helping a noob out!

Comment: The documentation addresses select2 directly. https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html

Comment: Yeah I saw that. But I figured this technically should work as well... Is there something I'm missing? Like directives dont like select2 or something? @BertEvans :\

Comment: There are some errors in your code. `data():{}`, for example, should be `data(){}`. `update` takes the same arguments as bind and not `oldVal, newVal` https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Directive-Hook-Arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as I mentioned in comments, I would suggest you do this with a component. If you *had* to stick with a directive, however, you can't initialize select2 in the `bind` hook. You've defined your options in the DOM, so you need to wait until the component is inserted to initialize it.

```
directives: {
    select: {
        inserted: function (el, binding, vnode) {
            var select = $(el);
            select.select2();
            select.on('change', function () {
                console.log('hey on select works!');
             });
        },
    },
},
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/esy6xx00/2/) is an update of your fiddle.