# vuejs with select 2 control missing

Tags: asp.net, vue.js, jquery-select2

[image]I have a very simple Vue js setup that I am trying to used to bind a select2 using a directive.  I would rather use a template but for reasons beyond my control I am actual forced to use an asp:DropDownList which means I am forced to have my select boxes inline on the client side.

So I am attempting to set up a Vue.directive but after executing the directive, the select2 is not anywhere to be found. Because the select2 was executed, the original select box get hidden and I end up with nothing showing on the page.

debugging stops are being hit and there are not errors being displayed in the console.

```
        <div id="tabUserInfo">
            <input id="myid" type="text" required="required"  ref="myid" v-model="firstName" />
            <span>{{firstName}}</span>
            <select id="sel" v-select2="''" v-model="optid">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>

        </div><script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                Vue.directive('select2', {
                    bind: function (elem, fieldName) {
                        $(elem).select2();
                        debugger;
                    },
                    unbind: function (elem) {
                        debugger;
                    }
                });
                var me = "Scott";
                var vm = new Vue({

                    el: '#tabUserInfo',
                    data: { firstName: 'Scott', optid:2 },
                });
            });

    </script>
```

Comment: When you say nothing showing on the page, do you mean no select is rendered on the client side?

Comment: Just that, the select2 code hides the original select box as per normal but then the select2 is not placed in its place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the hook from `bind` to `inserted`. It seems like select2 needs the element to be in the DOM in order to work correctly.

```
Vue.directive('select2', {
  inserted: function (elem, fieldName) {
    $(elem).select2();
  },
  unbind: function (elem) {}
});
```

In order to handle updates to a data value, the directive needs to be modified.

```
 Vue.directive('select2', {
   inserted: function (elem, binding, vnode) {
     let select = $(elem)
     select.select2();
     select.val(vnode.context[binding.expression]).trigger("change")
     select.on("change", function (evt) {
       vnode.context[binding.expression] = evt.target.value
     })
   },
   update: function (elem, binding, vnode) {
     let select = $(elem)
     select.val(vnode.context[binding.expression]).trigger("change")
   }
 });
```

Normally, `vnode` should be treated as a read only parameter, but given the constraints of your situation this directive cheats a little. Your dropdown should now be something like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Dropdown" v-select2="optid">
```

Note that the argument of the directive is the data property to bind. It replaces, `v-model`.

Comment: Thanks @Bert, I am playing with what you have listed and see if I can get it to work right.  My real page has 6 select boxes (some cascading) and 6 text boxes (its never easy)

Comment: @Bindrid I had a better idea. Change the hook from `bind` to `inserted`.

Comment: I tried inserted and the mounted method. However, while the select2 is now showing up as expected, and the select2 is updating the base select box as expected, the value (in this case, optid) is not getting updated in the vue model. I put a watch on it that logged to the console.

Comment: @Bindrid That's a separate issue. Funnily enough, I previously answered a question about setting up select2 with a directive [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42823959/38065). You're going to need to handle the change event as described there to update your id.

Comment: @Bindrid Updated with a directive that should update the value.

Comment: thanks so much. That does work.  I was missing the event handlers inside the directive

Comment: I replaced Knockout with Vue about two weeks ago on our project and have been going through the associated learning curve.

Comment: @Bindrid Vue is a great choice for integration with web forms among the prevalent frameworks. Have some older web forms I've used it with myself. Looks like this is only your second question; don't forget you can accept as well :)